# Can I use zxing library without unwanted permissions?

Tags: titanium, zxing

I am using barcode scanner module on my Titanium Android app to scan barcode. However, because of this library my app is requesting too many permissions from users which include READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS and WRITE_CONTACT. Obviously this is unnecessary and too intrusive for end-users.
Is there any way that I can remove some of the permissions?
I have already tried editing custom AndroidManifest file. But it always adds back those permissions in the .gen file.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with Titanium to build the app. Androidmanifest is not used by Titanium. It perhaps is generated by Titanium, but not used.

You need to edit the Tiapp.xml file, and remove the permissions you don't need from there. This way, it should not come back.

But as Sean Owen suggested, don't copy-paste an app, and use it for own purposses. If you just need a module, implement the module yourself, and use it from there.

Comment: I tried editing tiapp.xml, but as it only adds to AndroidManifest.xml, that doesn't help either. Of course, I know I have to modified the module as my last resort. I just wonder if there are other options. can someone provide more constructive answers?

Comment: have you removed your 'build' folder and build from scratch? The android manifest is build from the tiapp. So if you remove it there, it should be done

Comment: Thanks for all the hints! I got the solution. Just need to change the AndroidManifest.xml in the timodule.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a custom Manifest file in Titanium, by taking the generated Manifest file and paste it into the tiapp.xml. Titanium will use that one everytime instead of the generated one. Read more on how this works here http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/android-custom-androidmanifest